# Count number of characters of each word in a cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba, string, count

For instance if I have the sentence in one cell:

```
The fox jumped twice
```

the output should be

```
3 3 6 5
```

I've tried using the `len()` and `trim()` functions in a couple of combinations but didn't manage to find a solution yet, was afraid that it could be done only by using VBA.

Comment: A VBA function seems the best choice for this imo.

Comment: How many words can be in the different cells (the maximum?) It might be possible without VBA

Comment: @AlexK. you are definitely right.

Comment: @Pierre44 Usually 3-4 words, but it can go up to 8.

Comment: Old thread, but this is possible with normal function relatively easy. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58674097/9758194)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function count_Chars(ByVal target As Range)
Dim splt

splt = Split(target, " ")

Dim i As Long
Dim output As String

For i = LBound(splt) To UBound(splt)
    output = output & " " & Len(splt(i))
Next i

count_Chars = TRIM(output)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me a lot of time

Comment: @DavidGorgan - there are a few ways to do this, as the multiple answers show.  Whichever one works for you as your Answer, would you mind marking it as such by clicking the check mark left of the post?

Answer (score 1):

maybe with a loop?
Presuming that the words are separated by spaces:

```
Sub CountChars
    Dim strWord as Variant, lenWord as Long, StrCount as String

    For Each strWord in Split(mysheet.range("A1")," ")
        lenWord = len(strWord)

        'if you wish to display side by side:
        StrCount = StrCount & cstr(lenword) & " "
    Next
    StrCount = Trim(StrCount) 'To remove the space at the end from the last loop
    Debug.print StrCount

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this short array based UDF.

```
Option Explicit

Function wordLength(str As String)
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant
    arr = Split(str, Chr(32))
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = Len(arr(i))
    Next i
    wordLength = Join(arr, Chr(32))
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Just curious - why use `Chr(32)` instead of `" "`?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

A User-Defined-Function is a good idea, indeed:

```
Public Function CountWords(inString As String) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim myArr As Variant: myArr = Split(inString)
    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        CountWords = CountWords & " " & Len(myArr(i))
    Next i
    CountWords = Trim(CountWords)

End Function
```

- The `Split()` does not need an argument what to split with, if it is space;
- The `Trim()` removes the last space;

Answer (score 1):

Just to show the horrible answer you get without VBA:

You can look for the " " and then count the length between the different spaces.

```
=find(" ",B3,1)-1&" "&
find(" ",B3,find(" ",B3,1)+1)-(find(" ",B3,1))-1&" "&
find(" ",B3,find(" ",B3,find(" ",B3,1)+1)+1)-(find(" ",B3,find(" ",B3,1)+1)-(find(" ",B3,1))+find(" ",B3,1))-1&" "&
LEN(B3)-(find(" ",B3,1)+find(" ",B3,find(" ",B3,1)+1)-(find(" ",B3,1))+find(" ",B3,find(" ",B3,find(" ",B3,1)+1)+1)-(find(" ",B3,find(" ",B3,1)+1)-(find(" ",B3,1))+find(" ",B3,1)))
```

Comment: Woah, I really appreciate your effort xD.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **Characters.Count** property.

I got the following script from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters.count).

```
Sub MakeSuperscript() 
 Dim n As Integer 

 n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Characters.Count 
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Characters(n, 1) _ 
 .Font.Superscript = True 
End Sub
```

So in your case I believe if you were to use the `.split()` function to create an array of words. Then while looping through each element of the array you can use the `Characters.count()` property.