# Is there a way to count the number of characters per word for a string, returning values separated by a comma?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, word-count, charactercount

I have a list of strings in cells - 1000s of them - and I need to work out the characters per word but separated by word - preferably in 1 swift formula...

For Example:
1. "Black Cup With Handle" > Formula I need > 5,3,4,6

2. "Giant Bear Statue" > Formula I need > 5,4,6

I need this for a recurring task which has been macro'd in a very inefficient way to count words into columns (of which we need to use up to 20 for the just encase) but this needs to be tackled.

Usually, we count the spaces and layer nested serach() formulas to piggyback onto one and other to break down the structure then character counts the individual words...

I could alternatively the macro to substitute the spaces for commas and used text to columns but that still leaves me with a prolonged counting process for what im looking for

we obviously use `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))` to count the spaces in the word

we currently then use `=SEACRH()` function combined with `=MID()` functions (and some bizarre numbers) to reveal each word into its own individual cell

then `=LEN` once again bu on all individual words - very long-winded

Im hoping to find a shorter way to do this but feeling there may not be a dynamic enough way to do it with formula alone, hoping someone can prove me wrong!

Comment: The result needs to be in one column?  Just the numbers, like your example?

Comment: do you want a VBA code for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have different options depending on your Excel version.

---

***OPTION 1: `TEXTJOIN`***

I think you are looking for a `TEXTJOIN` function. Just bare in mind that you can only use this the more later versions of Excel (see link to documentation) and it could work like this:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,LEN(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))
```

> ***NOTE:*** It's an array formula and you need to enter it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

To make it so that you won't need to use the above key-combo, we can include an `INDEX`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(LEN(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")),))
```

---

**Additional Information:**

**[`FILTERXML`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**

This function takes (as per documentation) two required arguments:

- A string in valid **[XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp)**
- A string in valid **[XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)**

Because we want to return an array of elements (words) from the cell, we need to [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) the spaces for end-tags (`</..>`) and concatenate that with a start-tag (`<..>`) at the start of the string and another end-tag at the end.

I'll have to rely on an `XML` explaination on the tags as to why `<?><?>` works and it's meaning, because as far as my testing goes I could swap the letters around or replace by another letter with the same results as long as the final `Xpath` would resemble the same character. It would be great if someone would be able to complement this answer with a better explanation on this matter.

For more `FILTERXML` "tricks", have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194)

---

**[`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**

If you are a Office 365 subscriber or own Excel 2019 you can make use of this function. There are (as per documentation) at least 3 required arguments:

- A delimiter which must be a text string, either empty, or one or more characters enclosed by double quotes, or a reference to a valid text string. If a number is supplied, it will be treated as text.
- The second argument can hold either `TRUE` or `FALSE` and determines whether or not you want to exclude/include empty values
- The third argument is the text item to be joined. A text string, or array of strings, such as a range of cells.

Now this is where we can join the two functions together, `FILTERXML` returning an array which we can use in `TEXTJOIN`.

---

**[`INDEX`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)** + **[`LEN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/len-lenb-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**

I'll have to explain the use of these functions together. I don't think `LEN` and `INDEX` will need much of an introduction on their own, but together they work quite nicely. Natively there will be a force called implicit intersection that will prevent `LEN` from returning an array of values when you pass an array of values to the function, in this case through our `FILTERXML`.

Normally you would disable this mechanism using a key combination of: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, better known as `CSE`.

Now what `INDEX` does is disabling this implicit intersection making `LEN` able to return an array, removing the need to `CSE` the formula. `INDEX` is one of the functions that has this "power". A more in depth explanation on implicit intersection can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58536210/9758194)

---

***OPTION 2: UDF***

Without access to `TEXTJOIN` I think you'll need to have a look at using an UDF, possibly looking like below:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(rng As Range) As String
    TEXTJOIN = Join(Application.Evaluate("LEN({""" & Join(Split(rng, " "), """,""") & """})"), ",")
End Function
```

You can call this in `B1` like so: `=TEXTJOIN(A1)`

---

**Additional Information:**

The UDF consists out of three main mechanisms that work together:

**[`JOIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function)**

This funciton takes two parameters, where the first one is required:

- First parameter is a one-dimensional array containing substrings
- The second (optional) parameter is a string character used to separate the substrings in the returned string. If omitted, the space character (" ") is used. If delimiter is a zero-length string (""), all items in the list are concatenated with no delimiters.

The function returns a string value

---

**[`SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)**

This function takes a string and delimits it by a specified character/substring. It takes the following arguments:

- 1st: A required string expression containing substrings and delimiters. If expression is a zero-length string(""), Split returns an empty array, that is, an array with no elements and no data.
- 2nd: The optional delimiter which is a string character used to identify substring limits. If omitted, the space character (" ") is assumed to be the delimiter. If delimiter is a zero-length string, a single-element array containing the entire expression string is returned.
- 3rd: An optional limit, a number of substrings to be returned; -1 indicates that all substrings are returned.
- 4th: Compare, also optional, is a numeric value indicating the kind of comparison to use when evaluating substrings. See Settings section for values.

In this case we would only need the first two arguments.

---

**[`Application.Evaluate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate)**

This is IMO one of the most handy mechanisms you can use to pull of a returned array of values without having to loop through items/cells. It may get slow when you feed the function a large array formula, but in this case it will be fine. The funtion converts a Microsoft Excel name into an object or value, and when we pass it an formula, it thus will return the results. In this particular case it will return an array.

Comment: I like your tricky `FILTERXML` substitution very much; maybe worth some further explanations +:)

Comment: @JvdV - thank you very much for this, gonna make a massive improvement to some analytical things I have been working on!

Comment: @StewartGray, not a problem. It was a nice formulated question and fun to work on. I made a small adjustment, so that you won't have to enter it as an array formula.

Comment: @T.M. I've tried my best to explain the formula allthough the `FILTERXML` part, I'm no expert in. It would be nice to have someone explaining why `<?><?>` as start tags and `</?></?>` as end tags would work to seperate the words into an array.

Comment: The *words* (i.e. node contents between tags `<s>…</s>`) are returned as `NodeList` contents via the given XPath expression "//s" which searches for *any* node tag equal to "s" at any level within the XML structure (indicated by "//"); VBA treats these *list* as an array. You could search for a single expression e.g. via "//s[2]" returning only the second node or even for a condition within the node (alternatively XPath "t/s" searches only at Level 2 = 1 level after the starting `<t>` tag. And you could rename `t` to `root` and `s` to `item` to baptize them in a more meaningful way. @Jvdv :-)

Comment: @JvdV, ok, did understand the formula at once, was only suggesting to give further hints to people not so advanced in XML :-); congratulate you to the rich & helpful explanations given to many users (upvotes speak for themselves).

Comment: @T.M. your XML explanation does definitely help too. Thanks

Comment: Thx for the link which I appreciate as it enriches the officially existing documentation in an intensive and very helpful way :-) @JvdV

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally clear on what end-result you're looking for, or whether you're okay with a VBA solution, but this is my interpretation:

```
Function lengths(txt As String) As String
  Dim wrd
  For Each wrd In Split(txt)
    If lengths <> "" Then lengths = lengths & ","
    lengths = lengths & Len(wrd)
  Next wrd
End Function
```

Paste the code into a VBA module and then, for example, if `A1` contained `Black Cup With Handle` then in another cell you could use `=length(A1)` which would return `5,3,4,6`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a VBA code you could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            str = .Range("A" & i).Value

            arr = Split(str, " ")

            For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                .Cells(i, j + 3).Value = Len(arr(j))
            Next j

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]