# VBA Excel - How to display non equal values in an excel array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

[image: two]

So currently I have two DATA inputs in excel
Data 1 and Data 2
I need a formula or some sort to display results
*currently this is a manual process.

Comment: I know that we have to use a function under Split, and compare them both, then make it back to a 123, 124, 125 sequence form

Comment: Does that mean this is a homework problem, with constraints?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld nah it's just me being extra at work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach using `Filter()` function**

```
Function test(ByVal a, ByVal b, Optional Delim$ = ",") As String
'Purpose: return non unique values by comparing two comma separated string lists a vs. b
a = Split(a, Delim): b = Split(b, Delim)
Dim elem
For Each elem In b
    a = Filter(a, elem, False)  ' Include:=False, i.e. exclude non uniques
Next elem
test = Join(a, Delim & " ")
End Function
```

**Argument a:** 668,669,777,778,779,780,781,782,891,893,894,895

**Argument b:** 668,777,779,778,780,892,891,782

**Result string**        669, 781, 893, 894, 895

*BTW* the result shouldn't include 782 (c.f. OP) as this isn't a unique item.

**Caveat/Edit**

The above approach assumes three figure numbers only. As basically the `Filter` function executes a *partial string search* this would lead to unwanted results if you would be searching for e.g. `7` thus excluding any number containing `7`, as well. ~~> See revised code

**Revised code**

Allows only full string matches:

**Variant a) 2nd list contains doublettes, but is only a sub set of 1st list**

```
Function test(ByVal a, ByVal b, Optional Delim$ = ",") As String
'Purpose: return non unique values by comparing two comma separated string lists a vs. b
a = "$" & Replace(a, Delim, "$" & Delim & "$") & "$"
a = Split(a, Delim): b = Split(b, Delim)
Dim elem
For Each elem In b
    a = Filter(a, "$" & elem & "$", False)  ' Include:=False, i.e. exclude non uniques
Next elem
test = Replace(Join(a, Delim & " "), "$", vbNullString)
End Function
```

**Variant b) 2nd list contains also new numbers diferring from 1st list**

This might be the waterproof solution to your question (results corresponding to @RonRosenfeld 's fine solution).

```
Function test(ByVal a, ByVal b, Optional Delim$ = ",", Optional ByVal cnt% = 1) As String
'Purpose: return non unique values by comparing two comma separated string lists a vs. b
If cnt = 1 Then               ' recursive call to check 2nd string against 1st one
    test = test(b, a, Delim, 2)
    If Len(test) > 1 Then test = Mid(test, 1, Len(test) - 1)
End If
a = "$" & Replace(a, Delim, "$" & Delim & "$") & "$"
a = Split(a, Delim): b = Split(b, Delim)
Dim elem
For Each elem In b
    a = Filter(a, "$" & elem & "$", False)  ' Include:=False, i.e. exclude non uniques
Next elem
test = Replace(Join(a, Delim), "$", vbNullString) & Delim & test
If cnt = 0 Then test = Replace(test, Delim, Delim & " ")  ' add blank after delimiters
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The Variant a) is best suited for my case

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Excel 2016 or Office 365 with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can do this with an **array formula**

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Data_1,Data_2)," ",""),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[not( .=preceding::*) and not(.=following::*)]"))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]

- `TEXTJOIN` the strings using the comma delimiter

  - *If there are only two or three strings, you could use a simple concatenation and avoid the `TEXTJOIN` function, but you'd still need Excel 2013+ to have the `FILTERXML` function*
- Remove the spaces.  *If all delimiters are `<comma><space>` we could simplify the formula a bit.*
- Create an XML using the `<comma>` to define the nodes.
- the `xPath` says to return all nodes that are not followed by or preceded by it's duplicate.
- `TEXTJOIN` the resultant array

Comment: I'm using Office 2016

Comment: @Bamuel If you have the `TEXTJOIN` function, then the formula should work.

Comment: Your `XPath` expression in the `FilterXML` function is not only tricky, but proves to be very effective in this one line formula +1). - BTW Is there a common help source to the function's node naming using the same tags, i.e. `<t>` and `<s>`? .. c.f. a [recent post using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673369/is-there-a-way-to-count-the-number-of-characters-per-word-for-a-string-returnin/58674097#58674097) ? - @RonRosenfeld

Comment: @T.M. It doesn't make any difference how the nodes are named, so long as you use the same name for all the siblings, and a different name for the *wrapper*. One can, of course, create more complex xml's, but since what we're really doing is splitting a delimited string, and then applying an xPath to that, there's no need.

Comment: Thx for the quick & correct response, but I only wanted to know if there is a **common source** to refer as your post and the cited one above use the *same* naming convention (i.e. a `DocumentElement` wrapper named `<t>` and and a sub level node name `<s>`)  - *BTW Always enjoy your helpful Postings.* - @RonRosenfeld

Comment: @T.M. I dunno.  I noticed that naming convention being used by another, and I think the poster in your cited reference noticed my use of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function TEST(aString As String, aString2 As String, Optional Delimiter As String = ",") As String
    array1 = Split(aString, Delimiter)
    array2 = Split(aString2, Delimiter)

    Dim i 'As Integer
    Dim j 'As Integer
    Dim isFound 'As Boolean
    Dim output

    For i = 0 To UBound(array1)
        isFound = False
        For j = 0 To UBound(array2) - 1
            If array1(i) = array2(j) Then
                isFound = True
            End If
        Next 'j
        If Not isFound Then
            output = output + array1(i) & ", "
        End If
    Next 'i

    TEST = output
End Function
```

Comment: Friendly hint: Your `782` item isn't unique and shouldn't be occur in your list. Cause: in order to avoid a final delimiter in the result string your `j` loop *forgets* the last array2 item to be compared when counting only to `UBound(array2) - 1 instead to `UBound(array2)` only. Just replace the last delimiter character(s) by "" if the output len(gth) is greater than 0. (and don't forget to declare `array1` and `array2` as Variant; ~> Option Explicit!) - // FYI There are many ways leading to Rome, maybe you find my approach using the `Filter()` function helpful.